# select 36 characters of a string after a certain word and before a character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen lots of articles about selecting certain bits of data in SQL using substring and char index functions but nothing seemed to fit what I am trying to do or I'm unable to adapt them to my needs.

I am trying to select 36 characters after a certain word - the starting word being `systemuser|` and before a `;` that would be at the end of the string. And if there is more than one instance of `systemuser|` in the string, it should select the first one.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (col nvarchar(max))

INSERT INTO #Temp (col)
values ('account|f50aa0e3-2f87-e311-8502-005056b412da;systemuser|765e4a01-1802-e611-80dc-5065f38aca11;systemuser|9fa34207-1802-e611-80dc-5065f38aca11;account|0aa90a25-1786-e311-8502-005056b412da;contact|381e4b65-4387-e311-8502-005056b412da;contact|32eecd7a-dc8c-e311-8502-005056b412da;contact|2e536442-ebf7-e511-a997-005056b412da;contact|f45fac8d-4187-e311-8502-005056b412da')
,('contact|32eecd7a-dc8c-e311-8502-005056b412da')
,('systemuser|ab1852fb-1702-e611-80dc-5065f38aca11')
,('account|5d807c84-da86-e311-8502-005056b412da;systemuser|34ae3f0d-1802-e611-80dc-5065f38aca11')
,('account|08a90a25-1786-e311-8502-005056b412da;contact|369ede29-4287-e311-8502-005056b412da;systemuser|01ae3f0d-1802-e611-80dc-5065f38aca11')

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

So far I've tried lots of different combinations of `substring` and `charindex` but I'm afraid I can't get to grips with how it needs to be amended to select what I want.

```
SELECT 
      col
      ,CASE WHEN col LIKE '%systemuser|%' THEN SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('systemuser|', col), LEN(col)) ELSE NULL END AS TESTTHIS
      , SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('|', col), LEN(col))
      ,RIGHT(col, charindex('|', col) - 1)
      --,SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('systemuser|', col), CHARINDEX(';',col) - CHARINDEX('systemuser|', col) + Len(';'))
     -- ,CASE WHEN LEFT(col, 3) = 'sys' THEN right(col, charindex('systemuser|', reverse(col)) - 1) ELSE NULL END AS ToUser
     --,SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('systemuser|', col) + 10, CHARINDEX(';', col) - (CHARINDEX('systemuser|', col) + 12))
     --,SUBSTRING(col, LEN(LEFT(col, CHARINDEX ('systemuser|', col))) + 1, LEN(col) - LEN(LEFT(col, CHARINDEX ('systemuser|', col))) - LEN(RIGHT(col, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX (';', col))) - 1)
  FROM #temp
```

The commented out bits of code are the ones that don't work - I thought I'd paste them to show what I had tried.

Desired outcomes in order of rows above:

```
 '765e4a01-1802-e611-80dc-5065f38aca11'
 ,NULL
 ,'ab1852fb-1702-e611-80dc-5065f38aca11'
 ,'34ae3f0d-1802-e611-80dc-5065f38aca11'
 ,'01ae3f0d-1802-e611-80dc-5065f38aca11'
```

Could anyone be so kind as to help me with my problem I would be very grateful.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: just put down the sample data & desired o/p.

Comment: added my desired outcome - apologies, i don't know how to make it look formatted like you suggested in your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PATINDEX

```
SELECT 
    col, case when patindex('%systemuser|%', col) = 0 then NULL else
    SUBSTRING(col, patindex('%systemuser|%', col) + 11, 36) end
FROM #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Like following you ensure that `systemuser|` is followed by a GUID:

```
DECLARE @pattern varchar(273) = '%systemuser|[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]-[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]-[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]-[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]-[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%';

SELECT
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX(@pattern, col)=0 THEN NULL ELSE
    SUBSTRING(col, PATINDEX(@pattern, col)+11,36) END AS systemuserGUID
FROM #temp
```